# Why my simple AngularJS app can't work?

Tags: angularjs

I have the code as below which should popup an alert dialog while clicking "Alert AngularJS" button, but it doesn't. Can someone give me some advices?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"/>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            angular.module('app', []).run(function ($rootScope, $window) {
                $rootScope.myAlert = function () {
                    $window.alert('Hello AngularJS');
                };
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="app">
        <button ng-click="myAlert()">Alert AngularJS</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Works fine for me... see this jsfiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/DanielBank/U7t8G/).  Are you sure that angular is loading?  Any errors in the console log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"`**`/>`**

should be

`<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.js"`**`></script>`**